# Django returns false for form.is_valid() when submitting through request module

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms, request

I have a form in Django Application, which I am trying to submit through python request module.

Every time I tried to submit a form through request module it says that form is not valid.
form.is_valid() returns false in the django code.

However, if I submit the same form manually using browser it's submitted successfully.

**I am using following code to submit the form**

```
session = requests.session()
session.get("http://localhost:8000/autoflex/addresult/")
csrf_token = session.cookies["csrftoken"]

data = {"xml_url": xml_url, "csrfmiddlewaretoken": csrf_token}
result = session.post("http://localhost:8000/autoflex/addresult/", data=data, headers={"Referer": "http://localhost:8000/autoflex/addresult/"})
```

** following is the code from forms.py **

```
from django import forms

class SubmitForm(forms.Form):
    xml_url = forms.CharField()
```

**Following the template code. I am using crispy Forms.**

```
<!-- language: Python -->
<form method='POST' action=''>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form | crispy}}
    </br>
    <input class='btn btn-primary' type='submit' value='Submit'/>
</form>
```

**Following is the code from view.**

```
def add_result(request):
    form = SubmitForm(request.POST or None)
    context = dict(form=form, message="")

    is_duplicate = False

    if form.is_valid():
        #Original code is replaced with print statement
        print "form is valid"


    return render(request, "add_result.html", context)
```

Comment: what is an error ? What does the form.errors say ?

Comment: Please show the form and view.

Comment: @SebastianBurzyński  have updated the question.

Comment: @knbk **form.errors** is empty